# Nominatim - pgsql returned with error code (3)

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, nominatim, osm2pgsql

When I try to install new osm file in my nominatim server.

With the setup.php (10666 = 2/3 of 16G RAM) :

```
cd /srv/nominatim/build/ && ./utils/setup.php --osm-file /srv/nominatim/Nominatim-3.4.1/data/france-latest.osm --all --osm2pgsql-cache 10666
```

I have some errors :

```
Done 9254119 in 55677 @ 166.210800 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 8.447104
  Done 9254226 in 55679 @ 166.206757 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 7.803534
  Done 9254333 in 55680 @ 166.205688 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 7.159803
  Done 9254458 in 55681 @ 166.204956 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 6.407751
  Done 9254596 in 55682 @ 166.204453 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 5.577468
  Done 9254744 in 55683 @ 166.204117 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 4.687008
  Done 9254913 in 55684 @ 166.204163 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 3.670185
  Done 9255092 in 55685 @ 166.204407 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 2.593192
  Done 9255256 in 55686 @ 166.204361 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 1.606456
  Done 9255349 in 55688 @ 166.200058 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 1.046931
  Done 9255508 in 55689 @ 166.199936 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 0.090253
  Done 9255523 in 55689 @ 166.200195 per second - ETA (seconds): 0.000000
  Done 9255523 in 55689 @ 166.200195 per second - FINISHED

2020-09-10 09:07:48 == Index postcodes
2020-09-10 09:09:32 == Create Search indices
ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 10737418200.
ERROR: pgsql returned with error code (3)
string(34) "pgsql returned with error code (3)"
```

I've change many times the --osm2pgsql-cache parameters with some values : Same errors :(

My configuration :

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop41196p1  296G  167G  117G  59% /

:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            16G         56M         14G        1.2G        1.5G         14G
Swap:          256M        256M
```

Comment: It looks like a Postgres error, not a Nominatim one. You can increase the `maintenance_work_mem` configuration. See [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-parallel-create-index-for-better-performance/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I've this value in postgresql.conf : ```maintenance_work_mem = 10GB```. It's not enough ?. F.